# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. Class references maybe?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, null, typeerror

I get this error when I run my code:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference. at scripts::Enemy/moveToward()

I'm assuming it has something to do with registering the player on the stage. I have 3 classes so far: Engine, Player and Enemy. I'm currently building a side scrolling beat em up game.

```
package scripts 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Enemy extends MovieClip
    {
        var enemySpeed: Number = 3;
        var xDistance: Number = 50
        var yDistance: Number = 20;

        public var player: Player;

                public function Enemy()
                {
                        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addListeners)
                }

        public function addListeners(event: Event):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveToward);
            trace("handeled");
        }

        function moveToward(event: Event):void
        {
            if(this.x < player.x - xDistance)
            {
                this.x += enemySpeed;
                this.scaleX = -1;
            }
            if(this(root).x > player.x+xDistance)
            {
                this.x -= enemySpeed;
                this. scaleX = 1;
            }

            if(this.y < player.y-yDistance)
            {
                this.y += enemySpeed;
            }
            if(this.y > player.y+yDistance)
            {
                this.y -= enemySpeed;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add `trace("Player:", player)` at the top of `moveToward()`. I bet it will print `null` (or nothing).

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that "Player" is not initialized or instantiated when "moveForward" is called.  This usually happens during the first frame event in the movieclip.  You may consider adding a statement in moveForward method:

```
if ( player == null )
{
    return;
}
```